# Did John steal Primo's kilo in Five Star?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, five-star

At the end of [Five Star](http://fivestarthemovie.com/), John is accused of stealing Primo's kilo of cocaine.  The movie never actually shows John deliver the cocaine, as he claims.  Another man is murdered on John's attestation of innocence.  Soon afterward, John uncharacteristically pulls a gun on Primo, accusing him of having a hand in his father's death.

**Did John actually steal the kilo of cocaine in protest against Primo, or was he innocent as he claimed?**